# NDK unresolved inclusion but path is in local_c_includes for Bypass library

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, markdown

I'm trying to get the Bypass Markdown parsing library to work with my Android project.

I compiled Boost and installed it (because it's a dependency). Then I downloaded the Bypass source and imported the Android project as a library and included that in my own project properties as a library.

When I added NDK support to the project and rebuilt it, I noticed some errors in the Bypass project. I think it's caused by `unresolved inclusion "parser.h"`.

This is my Android.makefile:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
BYPASS_SRC := ../../../../src/

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := bypass
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    bypass.cpp \
    $(BYPASS_SRC)parser.cpp \
    $(BYPASS_SRC)document.cpp \
    $(BYPASS_SRC)element.cpp \
    ../../../../dep/libsoldout/markdown.c \
    ../../../../dep/libsoldout/buffer.c \
    ../../../../dep/libsoldout/array.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= ../../../dep/libsoldout ../../../src /opt/local/include /usr/local/include $(BYPASS_INCLUDE_PATH)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The `parser.h` file is in the `../../../../src/` folder. I checked it from the start of the makefile and it's in that exact folder, but it can't be found. What could be the cause of this?

By the way, this is my first time using the NDK and I have practically no C/C++ experience, so a detailed answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jni/Android.mk file, we set LOCAL_PATH and list the LOCAL_SRC_FILES relative to LOCAL_PATH. On the other hand, the list of LOCAL_C_INCLUDES contain directories that C and C++ compilers will search to resolve the #include directives in source files. These directories are relative to the project root directory (usually one level above LOCAL_PATH).

In your case, it's not clear how you checked the ../../../../src path to parser.h. Is this from the jni directory (where Android.mk is located), or from the project root?

Some more comments about your Android.mk file: because you are using cross-compiler, you should not look for include files in /opt/local or /usr/local/include directories.NDK should provide the platform- dependent alternatives. I colud not find BIPASS_INCLUDE_PATH defined.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still have no idea what steps I should take after reading that. It's the Android.mk from the `Bypass` library itself. Do I have to define `BYPASS_INCLUDE_PATH` the same as `BYPASS_SRC`?

Comment: Well you definitely put me on the right track. I set my `BYPASS_INCLUDE_PATH` as `:= ../../../src` and it compiled correctly and the library is working.